# solving a trig identities using formula $x^4+y^4$ but there is also a -1 what can i solve it

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know if I can use the formula $x^4+y^4$ even if it is $-1$ in the following expression

$$\frac{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x -1}{\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x -1}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598045/trigonometric-equation-2-sin6-x-cos6-x-3-sin4-x-cos4-x-0

Comment: Yes you can safely use $\displaystyle a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$ 

and  $\displaystyle a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$  with $a=x^2,b=y^2$

Comment: But I cannot solve it.

Comment: don't forget to use $a+b=1$ here

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "use the formula $x^4+y^4$", since it is not a formula, it is an expression.

Comment: Cab you help by solving it. I'm really so confused.

Comment: Use $\cos^4x = (1 - \sin^2 x )^2$ and $\cos^6x = (1 - \sin^2x)^3$ and simplify.  I think you'll this expression has a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \frac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x-1}{\sin^6x+\cos^6x-1}&=\frac{(1-\cos^2x)^2+\cos^4x-1}{(1-\cos^2x)^3+\cos^6x-1}\\
&=\frac{1-2\cos^2x+\cos^4x+\cos^4x-1}{1-3\cos^2x+3\cos^4x-\cos^6x+\cos^6x-1}=\frac{2\cos^4x-2\cos^2x}{3\cos^4x-3\cos^2x}\\
&=\frac23
\end{align*}$$
So it holds for every $x$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424825/find-all-different-integer-exponents